# Problem with verifying $-\nabla V = E$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

I have, at the four corners of a square $ABCD$ of side length $a$, listed cyclically, the charges $+2q, +q, +2q, -5q$.
When I calculate the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ at the centre of the square, I get

$$\mathbf{E} = \frac{12q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 a^2}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$$

from the principle of superposition of charges.

but when I calculate the potential at the centre, I get $V = 0$, again from superposition.

How can I fit this in line with the relation $-\nabla V = E$?

Comment: Your result for the field has a vector on the left and a number on the right.

Comment: @G.Smith My apologies, I missed a unit vector in the direction of the field; well spotted

Comment: You have to compute the three components of the field. From these you can get the magnitude and the correct unit vector.

Comment: What is your definition of $\hat{\bf r}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$V=0$ **at the center**, but how does $V$ change as you move away from that point?  $\nabla V$ doesn't care about the value of $V$, it cares about the *rate of change* of $V$.

More directly, the appropriate thing to do here would be to calculate $V(x,y)$ for arbitrary $x$ and $y$.  From there you can take your derivatives, and only at the end would you set $x$ and $y$ to the coordinates of the center of your square.  You should expect this exercise to be somewhat tedious. It’s also unnecessary - once you understand it for one particle it extends to many because differentiation is linear - but you may certainly do it if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know if I can do the rest mathematically with that understanding.

Comment: @J.Murray You comment should be incorporated in the answer.

Comment: @BillN Good point, done.

Answer (score 3):

To compute electric field from potential you have to have a continuous potential function $ V(x,y,z)$ first. Only then you can take the gradient and put $ x=a,y=b,z=c$ to calculate $\vec{E}$ at any particular point $(a,b,c)$.